# C macro, wrong argument number returned

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have following macros:

```
#define CONCATENATE(arg1, arg2)  arg1##arg2

#define FOR_EACH_1(what, x, ...) what(x)
#define FOR_EACH_2(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_1(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_3(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_2(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_4(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_3(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_5(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_4(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_6(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_5(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_7(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_6(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_8(what, x, ...) what(x) FOR_EACH_7(what, __VA_ARGS__)

#define FOR_EACH_NARG(...) FOR_EACH_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__, FOR_EACH_RSEQ_N())
#define FOR_EACH_NARG_(...) FOR_EACH_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_ARG_N(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, N, ...) N
#define FOR_EACH_RSEQ_N() 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

#define FOR_EACH_(N, what, x, ...) CONCATENATE(FOR_EACH_, N)(what, x, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH(what, x, ...) FOR_EACH_(FOR_EACH_NARG(x, __VA_ARGS__), what, x, __VA_ARGS__)
```

These are my test cases:

```
// does not work as intended (with one argument)
#define SOME(x) int x;
FOR_EACH(SOME, y)

// fine with 2 and more
FOR_EACH(SOME, y1, y2);
FOR_EACH(SOME, y3, y4, y5, y6);

// works fine even for one argument
#define ONLY(x) x
int FOR_EACH(ONLY, x);
```

Could please someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong for the case with only one argument, `#define SOME(x) int x`??

Compile it with `gcc -E macro.c -o macro.lol`, gives result:

```
int y; int ;  /* <-- that's wrong, why??? */

int y1; int y2;;
int y3; int y4; int y5; int y6;;


int x ;       /* <-- works as supposed */
```

Comment: Try giving that int a name.  It looks like it's name is missing.

Comment: `#define ONLY(x) x` is *not* working properly. It, too, gets called one extra time, with an empty x as argument. But because x is the whole output of the `ONLY` macro, you don't see that empty space. `#define SOME(x) int x;` outputs "int ", then x, then ";", and when *it* gets called with an empty x, you get the spurious `int ;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass two arguments to `FOR_EACH` (just the `what` and `x`), the `__VA_ARGS__` expands to nothing, and you have a trailing comma in the call to `FOR_EACH_NARG`, so it expands to 2 and therefore expands `FOR_EACH_2`.

You want to get rid of that trailing comma.  You can do that by either using the [non-standard extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) of using `##__VA_ARGS__` instead of `__VA_ARGS__`, which removes the comma before it only if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.  For a more standards-compliant version, you can combine the `x` and `__VA_ARGS__` into a single parameter:

```
#define FOR_EACH_(N, what, ...) CONCATENATE(FOR_EACH_, N)(what, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH(what, ...) FOR_EACH_(FOR_EACH_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), what, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thx you very much!! That's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should have seen some warning from your compiler, that you failed to tell us about.

My guess would be that your macro here

```
#define FOR_EACH_1(what, x, ...) what(x)
```

is wrong because it never sees a `__VA_ARGS__` part. I see two ways of healing that

```
#define FOR_EACH_1(what, ...) what(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOR_EACH_1(what, x) what(x)
```

Another thing that could hurt you with such macros is the different counting of argument numbers than you are used to with C.

```
#define MUCH(...)
#define NONE()

NONE   //<- this is considered receiving no argument
MUCH   //<- this receives one argument, the empty token list
```

If you are doing this for learning the preprocessor, this is fine :) if you really what a generic solution for this kind of problems you could have a look into Boost (but this is mainly C++) and [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don't get any warning from my compiler: gcc 4.5.3